# ServiceStack - Email Confirmation

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, .net-core, authorization, servicestack

I'm trying to implement email confirmation in ServiceStack. I've spent 5 days trying to make sense of all the authentication mechanism, and I must say it's very complex. The code not easy to read.

I have a hard time knowing for example :

- Why is `IAuthProvider.OnAuthenticated` called? Sometimes it seems like it's optional.
- Why is `IAuthSession.PopulateSession` called? How is it different from `IAuthProvider.PopulateSession`?
- Why is `IRequest.SaveSession` called?
- What are `IAuthTokens`? And why are they merged at some point? Is it because a user can be authenticated with many different providers, and we need to merge the `IAuthTokens`? Are they like claims ?
- Is `Session.FromToken` only for JWT ?
- How are `IAuthWithRequest.PreAuthenticate` and `IAuthProvider.Authenticate` different? What should be done differently in either method? I gather that PreAuthenticate is called on every request, and Authenticate is called when using the /auth/{provider} (in this case /auth/email). Am I missing something?

With these questions aside, to solve the problem, I tried two approaches :

1. Implementing a EmailConfirmationAuthProvider

   1. Override the default `UserAuth` with `CustomUserAuth` by adding a `bool EmailConfirmed {get;set;}` field.
   2. When user signs up, an email is sent to the user with a secret token. This token is stored somewhere.
   3. When the user clicks on the link (https://blabla.com/auth/email?token=abcdef), the `EmailConfirmationAuthProvider.PreAuthenticate` will mark the `CustomUserAuth.EmailConfirmed` as true if the token is valid and not expired. The token is deleted so impossible to authenticate again with that token.
   4. I don't know how to add the `EmailConfirmed = true` to the session, nor how to add it on subsequent logins. And I don't know how not to get in the way of other authentication mechanisms.
2. Implementing a `EmailConfirmationService`

   1. (Same steps as 1.1 and 1.2)
   2. When the user clicks on the link (https://blabla.com/email-confirmation?token=abcdef), the `EmailConfirmationService` will mark the `CustomUserAuth.EmailConfirmed` as true if the token is valid and not expired. Token is deleted and impossible to re-use the same token.
   3. I don't know how the session can be re-populated from the `CustomUserAuth`, especially if the user is already authenticated with a JWT token (if `JwtAuthProvider` is part of the `AuthFeature.AuthProviders`). I want to find a way to add a EmailConfirmed flag to the session for all subsequent logins of that user. I didn't find how to "modify" the JWT token (by adding a EmailConfirmed = true), and send it back as a cookie so that it's not necessary to check if the email is confirmed on every request.

Basically, I want to restrict access to all services marked with `[Authenticate]` to users that have confirmed their email addresses. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this should only apply to users that signed up using credentials (email confirmation should not apply if user signs in with `GoogleAuthProvider`..? Or should it?)

Exception to this rule would be for some services (marked with an attribute say `[AllowUnconfirmedEmail]`) that allow a user to re-send a confirmation email to their address (say they entered the wrong e-mail address). The `EmailConfirmationService` could allow authenticated users to send a new confirmation to a new address. Once that confirmation email is clicked, the `CustomUserAuth.Email & CustomUserAuth.PrimaryEmail` will be updated with the new address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to the high-level diagrams in [ServiceStack Authentication Docs](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization) to explain how [session based Auth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#session-authentication-overview) and [`IAuthWithRequest` Auth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers) work.

A lot of these questions are internal implementation details, they're called when they're needed by their different Auth Providers. The user overridable events you can add custom logic to are published in [Session and Auth Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events).

`PreAuthenticate()` are called by [`IAuthWithRequest` Auth Providers](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers) that authenticate per-request like [API Key](https://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider)  and [JWT](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider) Auth Providers. `Authenticate()` are called when authenticating via `/auth` provider.

#### Implementing am Email Confirmation

The easiest way to implement users requiring a confirmed email would likely be to implement a [Custom UserSession Validation](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#usersession-validation) something like:

```
public class CustomUserSession : AuthUserSession
{
    public override IHttpResult Validate(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, 
        IAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {
        using (var db = HostContext.AppHost.GetDbConnection(authService.Request))
        {
            var userAuthId = int.Parse(session.UserAuthId);
            if (!db.Exists<CustomUserAuth>(x => x.Id == userAuthId && x.EmailConfirmed))
                return HttpError.Conflict($"Email not confirmed") as IHttpResult;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So it only allows Authentication if the user has a confirmed email address.

Please see [Extending UserAuth Tables](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#extending-userauth-tables) for how to use Custom `UserAuth` tables with additional metadata like `EmailConfirmed`.

Your Email Service would then be a Service that accepts a random string like a `Guid` (Either in `CustomUserAuth` or a separate table) that references which user has confirmed their email. Alternatively the link in the email can just include the email again in which case you can match it against the existing Email in the `Email` field in the `CustomUserAuth` table.

If you then want to Authenticate the User in the same request you can allow [password-less Authenticated requests](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#in-process-authenticated-requests) by configuring your `CredentialsAuthProvider` with:

```
new CredentialsAuthProvider {
    SkipPasswordVerificationForInProcessRequests = true,
}
```

Which will then let you authenticate in the same "in process" request with just the username:

```
using (var service = base.ResolveService<AuthenticateService>()) //In Process
{
    return service.Post(new Authenticate {
        provider = AuthenticateService.CredentialsProvider,
        UserName = request.UserName,
        UseTokenCookie = true, // if using JWT
    });
}
```

You can use [UseTokenCookie to authenticate the User with a HTTP Only JWT Session](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#request-jwt-cookie-is-set-on-authentication), although using JWT isn't required.

It's not required for this solution, but you can add additional info to the JWT Token by [implementing CreatePayloadFilter](https://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#modifying-the-payload) and have that additional metadata populated on the User Session by implementing `PopulateSessionFilter`.

> I don't know how to add the EmailConfirmed = true to the session

You can populate the UserSession by implementing `OnAuthenticated()` on your Custom `AuthUserSession`.

> Basically, I want to restrict access to all services marked with [Authenticate] to users that have confirmed their email addresses.

Overriding `Validate()` in your Custom AuthUserSession as above will ensure that only users with confirmed emails can authenticate.

> Exception to this rule would be for some services

There is no concept of "partially authenticated user" you're either authenticated (and have an Authenticated UserSession attached to the Request or Cache) or you're not. I would only allow Authentication if they've confirmed their email and only update their confirmed email if they've confirmed their proposed email they want to change it to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I started following these guidelines. It seems that CreadentialsAuthProvider doesn't call CustomAuthSession.Validate though. 


I've overridden the AuthSession with CustomAuthSession, registered it in the SessionFactory of AuthFeature, overridden the "Validate" method, but it doesn't get called when user authenticates. I made sure to delete the cookies in the browser as well to "force" it.

Comment: Also, I found that `PopulateSessionFilter` will only be called if authenticating via a JWT. It will not be called if authenticating via `CredentialsAuthProvider` with `Authenticate.UseTokenCookie = true`. I would expect to be the case, since let's say I would like to add a "EmailConfirmed" property to the JWT, I would expect that this method be called and the cookie be set on the browser, containing this "claim". So that subsequent requests with that JWT will not need to make a trip to the DB to check if the email is confirmed for example.

Comment: @LudovicC `IAuthSession.Validate()` is [now being called](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/a6c67f52e9a94626cf99101665d53fdd15bf56d3) in overridden Auth Providers like Credentials Auth, now available from v5.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/a6c67f52e9a94626cf99101665d53fdd15bf56d3).

Comment: @LudovicC As per my answer use `CreatePayloadFilter` to add metadata in the JWT and `PopulateSessionFilter` for populating the UserSession from the `JsonObject` jwtPayload.

Comment: I installed 5.5.1 but it seems the changes are not in this version :/

Comment: @LudovicC The [change is definitely on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/a6c67f52e9a94626cf99101665d53fdd15bf56d3), try [clearing your NuGet Packages Cache](https://docs.servicestack.net/myget#redownloading-myget-packages)